# Python - Calling a script from another script and handling exceptions from the second one

Tags: python, exception

So I have this script, a python script (call it AAA.py) and it calls a method in another python script (call it BBB.py).
Now this method in BBB.py throws and handles a KeyError exception but when I run AAA.py it raises the exception to my console as if it wasn't handled... and I don't understand why.
Could someone explain this to me please?

Yes I've read the documentation on exceptions in python.

Here is the Try/Except:

```
try:
    if network['network'] == vlans_dict[network['netName']]['netaddr']:
        self.test_pass('Network address matches VLAN Router: ' + str(network['network']))
    else:
        self.test_fail('Network address does not match VLAN Router: ' + network['netName'],
                        'Expected: ' + str(vlans_dict[network['netName']]['netaddr']),
                        'Actual: ' + str(network['network']))
except KeyError:
    self.test_fail("No subnet obtained for " + network['netName'] + " from VLAN info")
```

Honestly it would be ridiculous to add the rest of the code...

So just to add a bit more to this... if I run the second script directly on it's own it handles the exception as gracefully as intended.

Regards,
J

Comment: can u show the code

Comment: Would you like to see the Try/Except?

Comment: Maybe the exception is being thrown somewhere else. Look at the line number.

Comment: Keyerror on which key? Maybe the key netName does not exist. Please post the Exception message.

Comment: Thanks Rishav that occurred to me after like a day of looking at this! lol but yeah I checked and it is that try that the exception is coming from :)

Comment: @W.Mann 'netaddr' but does it matter? A KeyError is a KeyError surely?

Comment: @JasonO'Connor: I wanted to rule out that the exception comes from a KeyError in your exception handler.

Comment: @W.Mann ahh I see, good point, wouldn't even have spotted that myself! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right.... short answer: I'm an absolute grade A f**kin idiot...

Longer answer: I was modifying a copy of BBB.py which was *not* the BBB.py that AAA.py was getting from the class path... So the code was fine, I just wasn't actually running it!